# How to show album title for 'album with no photos' in view

Tags: views, media

I am using node gallery module to create albums and upload photos. I have created a view to create albums and upload photos.It is working fine.But when i create album with no photos, album title is not getting displayed.I want to show 'default image and title of the album' for 'albums with no photos'.I have specified 'title and default image' in 'content:photo' no result behaviour in my view and Only the node author can see this but other users are not able to view this album. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also seem to have a permission issue. Maybe some of your nodes aren't published. Check that first. If you are unsure set your views'Query settings' to 'Disable SQL rewriting' and see if it works. If it does then it is definitely a permission issue which you need to track down. It is not advisable unless you are doing it by design to leave Disable SQL rewriting on. And if you are using the file entity then also check the permission there.

Comment: I set the 'Disable sql rewriting' in views query setting and its working fine.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of two ways:

1) Create a Header. Under Header (middle of page) create a Global Text. This will create a title for the View regardless of it's contents

2) Under Advanced, create a NO RESULTS BEHAVIOUR. This functions on the view as a whole, so that if there is not content to display at all, this will be displayed